# How to get Firefox Web Extension's "Internal UUID" from Selenium script?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I need to open `moz-extension://internal-uuid` page after my Selenium script is started to have an access to the extension's `storage API`, to set some prefs there, that this extension will read later and use to do some actions. But when I use `selenium.webdriver.Firefox.add_addon(...)` it returns the `Extension ID` that differs and can't be used to open the `moz-extension://` page. Is there any way to get this `Internal UUID` from my code (not manually by inspecting `about:debugging#addons`). Or may be some way to pass the data I need from Selenium to Web Extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is working for me in Linux and Mac:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();

    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

    String userPrefsFileContent = readFile(driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("moz:profile") + "/prefs.js");

    String extensionUuid = getExtensionUuid(userPrefsFileContent);

    driver.quit();

}

private static String getExtensionUuid(String userPrefsFileContent) {

    String uuid = null;

    String[] usersPrefsList = userPrefsFileContent.split(";");

    for (String currentPref : usersPrefsList) {

        if (currentPref.contains("extensions.webextensions.uuids")) {
            uuid = currentPref.split(":")[1].replaceAll("\"", "").replace("}", "")
                    .replace(")", "").replace("\\", "");
        }

    }

    if(uuid.contains(",")) {
        uuid = uuid.split(",")[0];
    }

    return uuid;

}

private static String readFile(String pathname) throws IOException {

    File file = new File(pathname);
    StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder((int) file.length());
    String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            fileContents.append(scanner.nextLine()).append(lineSeparator);
        }
    }
    return fileContents.toString();
}
```

Comment: so actually you inspect `extensions.webextensions.uuids` in `about:config`. sounds interesting

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how, but I cannot get this approach to work in python, so instead found out another smart approach, instead of trying to get preference that is not provided by Firefox, you can set UUID to something with `set-preference` API. then just use it.
here is part of my code

```
if self.webdriver != None:
            return self.webdriver

        extensionPath = curPath+'/../../packages/firefox.xpi';
        cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
        cap["marionette"]=True;
        profile = webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile();
        profile.set_preference('extensions.webextensions.uuids',json.dumps({'support@ipburger.com':firefoxUUID}))
        self.webdriver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=firefoxBinary,capabilities=cap,executable_path=curPath+'/../../drivers/geckodriver',firefox_profile=profile);
        self.webdriver.install_addon(extensionPath,temporary=True);
        return self.webdriver;
```

firefoxUUID is a string version of random UUID you generate
and you have to replace `support@ipburger.com` with your addon ID, which you can set inside manifest.json file

Comment: Unfortunately, profile was deprecated...

Answer (score 0):

the code below is working for me in python on windows :

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=firefox_service, options=firefox_options)
driver.install_addon(os.path.join(application_path, 'extension_firefox.xpi'), temporary=True)

time.sleep(1)

profile_path = driver.capabilities['moz:profile']

with open('{}/prefs.js'.format(profile_path), 'r') as file_prefs:
    lines = file_prefs.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if 'extensions.webextensions.uuids' in line:
            sublines = line.split(',')
            for subline in sublines:
                if id_extension_firefox in subline:
                    internal_uuid = subline.split(':')[1][2:38]
```